# SF2 - Doctrine DQL - Select several columns

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a table Item with the following columns:

- Id
- Category
- value
- date

I build a SQL request which returns all the lines with the latest date for each category:

```
SELECT *
FROM item i
WHERE (i.category, i.date) IN (SELECT category, MAX(date)
                               FROM item
                               GROUP BY category)
```

This works fine and returns what I need.

I work with Symfony2 and Doctrine, so I would prefer to use DQL (or even better: the QueryBuilder) instead of NativeSQL.

So here is my DQL request :

```
SELECT i
FROM MyBundle:Item i
WHERE (i.category, i.date) IN (SELECT i2.category, MAX(i2.date) 
                               FROM MyBundle:Item i2
                               GROUP BY i2.category
                               )
```

Which gives me the error:

```
QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 103: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS, got ','
```

If I remove the first couple of parenthesis, I get :

```
QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 102: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got ','
```

I thought there was a problem with the WHERE so I tried the following just to see what would happen:

```
SELECT i
FROM MyBundle:Item i
WHERE i IN (SELECT i2.category, MAX(i2.date) 
            FROM MyBundle:Item i2
            GROUP BY i2.category
            )
```

I get:

```
QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 116: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_FROM, got ','
```

But in the doctrine doc, [there is an example](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples) with several columns after the SELECT, using this same syntax!

Do you have any idea where does my problem come from?
Thank you!
Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `exists`:

```
SELECT 
  i 
FROM 
  MyBundle:Item i 
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT i2 
    FROM MyBundle:Item i2
    WHERE i2.category = i.category
    GROUP BY i2.category
    HAVING MAX(i2.date) = i.date
  )
```

Comment: Thanks! This is much more convenient for me. The re-writting of the request is sometimes the best way out!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to separate the query's conditional statements; This is because DQL is unable to parse the comma separated field names `(i.category, i.date)`.

```
SELECT 
  i 
FROM 
  MyBundle:Item i 
WHERE
  i.category IN ( (SELECT i2.category FROM MyBundle:Item i2 GROUP BY i2.specy) )
AND
  i.date IN ( (SELECT MAX(i2.date) FROM MyBundle:Item i2 GROUP BY i2.specy) )
```

I would also recommend using parentheses `()` to wrap any sub queries.

Comment: It works, thanks. I had to change the second group of i2 by i3, otherwise it said that i2 is already defined. Isn't there a more elegant way to do this, though? To me, it looks more like a workaround than an example of "best pratice". I mean, it is way harder to read than the pure SQL version!

Comment: @Blacksad Short of [creating a custom AST walker](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/cookbook/dql-custom-walkers.html) (which would be fairly complex and of course produce the same end result anyway) this would be the easiest method. Feel free to [accept the answer as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it solved your issue

Comment: Well, I think I'll come back to native SQL, the DQL formalism is counter-productive in this case. This is not the answer I hoped but apparently this is the correct answer!